# Can't start an Azure virtual machine which is in Available status

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

An Azure virtual machine displays the status "Available".

[image]

After clicking on "start", Azure will give the notification message "Starting the virtual machine", it will then give the message that the machine has started, however I can't connect to it and the page will still have the "start" button active along with the "stop" button.

[image]

This status doesn't seem to be well documented either.

What is the meaning of this status and which could be the possible reasons why the machine can't be started?

Comment: Try contacting tech support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go Serial console option and check what the status shows 
Try using; [PowerShell](http://%20https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495226.aspx) to force start the virtual machine.

If the issue still occurs; Maybe you can resize the instance of the virtual machine, making it larger. If it does not work, you can delete and recreate the virtual machine. When you delete the virtual machine, please detach the data disk from the virtual machine.

You could resize the VM as per your requirement and to the available VM size, kindly refer the link below for more details on this: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn168976(v=nav.70).aspx

Troubleshoot Remote Desktop connections to an Azure virtual machine
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-rdp-connection

Additional information: 
On the Azure portal, Select your VM -> Settings -> Boot diagnostics. Make sure that you can see the login screen. You might need to enable diagnostics (under Monitoring section) if not enabled already. If you don't see the login screen, trying the 'Redeploy' option under 'Support and Troubleshooting' section of settings.
If you can see that the machines has booted correctly, the connectivity issue might be because of a firewall at your end or on the VM. See if you can ping the machine. If you are behind a corporate firewall, try connecting from elsewhere and check your PC's firewall.

Just for clarification: If you are using Azure Dev test lab
[Using Command Line Tools to Start and Stop Azure DevTest Lab Virtual Machines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devtestlab/2018/06/12/using-command-line-tools-to-start-and-stop-azure-devtest-lab-virtual-machines/)

Activity logs are good place to look if you are investigating a failure sometime after attempted creation of your vm or environment.  Let's go over how to find logs for both environments and virtual machines.

[Start a DevTest labs VM via powershell](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ce411fe-8e60-4b04-9454-ee7463606d0e/start-a-devtest-labs-vm-via-powershell?forum=AzureDevTestLabs)

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.